# How should I sketch this, for the cases $k = 0$ and $k=1$?

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections, tangent-line

I was trying to solving the problem that involves sketching the tangent line to the ellipse:
$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{b^2}{a^2}=1$.
I was asked by the problem to prove that:
The tangent line to the ellipse to the point $(acos(\alpha), bsin(\alpha))$ can be written in the form:
$y=\frac{-(1-k^2)b}{2ka} x + \frac{b(1+k^2)}{2k}$ where $k=tan(\frac{\alpha}{2})$ . 
And after that, the problem requires me to test whether when $k=0$ and $k=1$, the line is still a tangent to the ellipse by means of sketch.

May I know how can I sketch the tangent as when $k=0$, the gradient cannot be calculated, since the denominator is $0$. So How can I do this?

Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: Rather than thinking about the equation you found for $y$... think about it from the other side... You have an ellipse centered on the origin.  What is the tangent for the ellipse for the point corresponding to $\alpha = 0$?  It is simply going to be a vertical line, right?

Comment: I now quite get it thank you,,, I have sketched a vertical line for only a few times in my life ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $k = 0$, $\alpha = 0$.  When $\alpha = 0$, the point of the ellipse is the rightmost point, at which the slope of the tangent is undefined (the tangent line is vertical).  So you know a point on and the direction of the tangent line when $k = 0$, so you can sketch that line.

Comment: But, the problem is...when k = 0; thus, $\alpha =0$, I only know 1 point,, how can I know that the tangent would be the vertical line..is it because its grandient cannot be identified? So, If I have a tangent, that cannot be identified, and I know 1 point, I know it will be a vertical line that passes that point.

Comment: You know it is vertical because you know the tangent to the right and left ends of an ellipse are vertical.  Notice that you have the same problem with $k$ when $\alpha = \pi$ and $-\pi$ which correspond to the left-most point of the ellipse, where the tangent line is vertical again.

Comment: @HenryCai : You are not using an algebraic property of the expression for a non-vertical line $y = \dots x + \dots$.  You are using facts you know about ellipses.

Comment: Can I think in this way? Because the tangent cannot be found -> It is vertical -> It is the tangent to the left or right-ends

Comment: @HenryCai : The best you can infer from the division by zero you notice is either (1) the slope is vertical so this expression cannot possible represent the line or (2) the expression or the derivation of the expression contains a step which prevents representation of the correct line.  To conclude the first, you would have to conclusively exclude the second.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression for the tangent line is derived with a division by $k$, which is not allowe when $k=0$.  If you go back to the definition of $k$ you find that $\alpha=0$, so the point in question is $(a,0)$  The tangent is then vertical, so the equation is $x=a$.  You can declare that the given equation for the tangent line is wrong because it divides by $k$.  You should be able to derive the correct equation if you go back through the definition to before the division by $k$ and set $k=0$

Comment: Thank you, so the fact that the unidentifiable nature of the gradient would mean the line is vertical.

Comment: Many expressions for straight lines do not treat vertical lines correctly.  If you think of the usual $y=mx+b$ that applies as well.  You can get any angle of the line except vertical with that.  I would not say the fact that the equation fails means the line is vertical, but in practice it is likely.  You should look at the problem to see what went wrong.